# Get web server site via Java agent in lotus notes?

Tags: java, lotus, agent

Is it possible to dynamically create internet sites rule(substitutions) on lotus web server via Java agent?

Answer (score 2):

The rules are stored in "normal" Notes documents. That means you can create, edit and delete such rules (=documents) using Java.

How to do this?

Create some Web Site Rules manually like shown [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.help.domino.admin.doc/DOC/H_WEB_SITE_RULES_OVERVIEW.html).

Look then in Domino Directory Database for created Web Site Rule documents and discover with Files\Properties which fields are in such documents. Then you know, how the documents have to look like you'll create with Java.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible, BUT: As every substitution rule needs a restart of the http- task, the documents would not be available directly...

Here is part of the code. In an Agent do the following:

```
Session session = getSession();
AgentContext agentContext = session.getAgentContext();
Database db = agentContext.getCurrentDatabase();
Document doc = db.createDocument();
doc.replaceItemValue("Form", "WebRule" );
//.... WebRule documents can never stand alone, they have to be "attached" to a 
//internetsite as Responses. I forgot about this in the first run.
Document docInternet = db.getDocumentByUNID( "PasteUNIDofInternetSiteDocumentHere" );
doc.makeResponse(docInternet);
//.... Fill the fields that you found out like explained by Knut Herrmann
doc.replaceItemValue( .... );
doc.replaceItemValue( .... );
doc.replaceItemValue( .... );
doc.replaceItemValue( .... );
// for lacy programmers who do not want to set all the hidden fields by themselves
doc.computeWithForm(false, false);
doc.save( true, true, true );
```

Comment: "As every substitution rule needs a restart of the http- task" Yes, i know. Show please the way to create rules.

Comment: Sidenote: in most cases you can do a "tell http refresh" in order for rules to be updated (and thereby avoid restarting HTTP)

Comment: thx a lot, i use folowing code:
          `doc.appendItemValue("Comment", "testingFromJA");
          doc.appendItemValue("MappingType", 1);
          doc.appendItemValue("RM_MapFrom", "/remap");
          doc.appendItemValue("RM_MapTo", "/yc_copy.nsf");` but after refresh http server when i try go to mySiteName/remap i have an error `Http Status Code: 404 Reason: File not found or unable to read file`. BUT, when i manually create rule substitution (/remapp - /yc_copy.nsf) - it work correctly

Comment: First of all: please use "replaceItemValue"... "appendItemValue" might result in wrong results... but your error is: "MappingType" is a text. So it has to be: doc.replaceitemValue( "MappingType" , "1" ). best thing would be to create a document like you do and create one manually. Then select them in the view and export them using the  File->Export- menu as Structured text. Then you can find out the differences easily...

Comment: When I manually create a doc of this type and export it, a lot more fields than the fiew mentioned in your code are set. Not all of them for sure are neccessary, but at least "RM_AccessLevel" could be worth a try. If you do not want to fill all the fields "manually", then try to add a doc.computeWithForm(false, false) before your doc.save

Comment: I would also set the Type- Field to "WebRule", the Type- Fields in the names.nsf are mostly very important...

Comment: maybe it not working becouse i have a 3 sites on this server?) How do i know what rule created for current web-site?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30778/discussion-between-ivan-podgornyy-and-tode)